# Writing Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I haven't written many stored procedures with oracle.  I read through some tutotorials (for example:  http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-procedures.htm) and tried to model my sp after what I saw, but I am still encountering an error.  Here's is a small sample procedure and error:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE TEST_SP()
  BEGIN

insert into tablespace.tablename
select * from testtable;

END TEST_SP;

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
```

I get the impression that I am missing the declaration section, but I do not understand what I am supposed to be declaring :-/

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Followed Justin's advice from first response, now getting different error:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE TEST_SP
 AS
  BEGIN

insert into tablespace.tablename (col1, col2)
select (col1, col2) from testtable;

END TEST_SP;

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the following: 
. , @ in <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> partition subpartition
```

Comment: What tool are you using?  Can you try in SQL*Plus to make sure that your aren't having problems with your tool (particularly in GUI applications where there may be prior unterminated SQL statements)?  If you are actually using the name of the tablespace rather than the name of the schema in your `INSERT`, you'd get an ORA-00942 error.  Generally, you wouldn't put parenthesis around the column names in your `SELECT` though the syntax you posted is valid.

Comment: You're right, I'm using schema name and not tablespace.  I am using sqldeveloper.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't another SQL statement above your `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` statement that isn't ended correctly?  Can you run the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` statement in SQL*Plus?

Comment: I don't think I have that installed on my db server.

Comment: But I can confirm that there is no other statement or even spaces above the start of my stored procedure.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to install a database without having SQL*Plis installed.  At the command prompt, type `sqlplus`

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free.  Please learn to use it rather than cluttering SO with trivial syntax questions. Here is the entry for INSERT.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2163698  As you will see in the given examples, we don't put brackets around the projection of a SELECT statetment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're after something like this.  You don't want to have parenthesis after the name of the procedure if you are not declaring any parameters.  And you need the keyword `AS` (or `IS`) before your `BEGIN` even if you're not going to declare any local variables.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_SP
AS
BEGIN
  insert into tablespace.tablename
    select * from testtable;
END TEST_SP;
```

Generally, however, it's a bad idea to write code like this that omits the list of columns.  That assumes that the two tables have exactly the same columns defined in exactly the same order so if someone decides to add another column to one of the tables, your code will break.  It also creates the possibility that you're inadvertently copying data from the wrong column.  It is generally more robust to write something like

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_SP
AS
BEGIN
  insert into tablespace.tablename( <<list of columns>> )
    select <<list of columns>>
      from testtable;
END TEST_SP;
```

As an example

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> create table foo_cpy( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace procedure test_sp
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    insert into foo( col1 )
  5      select col1
  6        from foo_cpy;
  7* end test_sp;
SQL> /

Procedure created.
```

Comment: Thanks, Justin.  You're right about the column names; I just wanted a quick way to demonstrate my problem while preserving the main point (stored procedure error) without giving away any real data.

Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried, but am now getting : "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the following:

   . , @ in <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> partition subpartition
""

Comment: @BadProgrammer - I posted an example that shows the syntax working.  Can you update your question to include the code you're currently using?